# How to get binary data from RestTemplate or WebClient in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webclient

I need to call an API from my microservice which returns binary file data which i have to return back to the requester system
I tried using below code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getDocument", method=RequestMethod.POST)
private ResponseEntity<byte[]> receiveFile(){
  MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
  map.add("mobile","XXXXXXXXX9");
  WebClient webClient = WebClient.create();
        ResponseEntity<byte[]> apiResponse = webClient.post()
                .uri(new URI("https://api.myapp.net.in/getDocument"))
                .header("username", "xyz")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
                //.accept(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"))
                .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData(map))
                .retrieve()
                .toEntity(byte[].class)
                .block();
      return apiResponse;
}
```

When i execute the above code and try to consume from Postman i am getting error as unable to open file but when i directly call the https://api.myapp.net.in/getDocument API via Postman i am able to download the pdf file properly.

Please let me know where am i going wrong.

Comment: what do you mean by "execute the above code and try to consume from Postman" ? in your code you use a post request which is not used for getting data as the name suggests.

Comment: I completely agree with your point but the consuming api is not developed by me it is developed by some other vendor and it is consumed by many of his clients. And i have written the above code to consume the vendors API. Hope now i am clear.